# Woocommerce storefront child theme with two thumbnail sizes product image and category image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am trying to customize the Woocommerce Storefront theme by creating a child theme.
It seems that the theme is using the same thumbnail size for both the categories, and the products.
How would I make two different sizes one to dispaly the category thumbnails, and one the product thumbnails?